# How can I replace a scaffolded controller action and still call the original in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I need to 'override' a scaffolded action in a controller, do some stuff and then invoke the original. I would prefer to use the dynamically generated method and not have to cut and paste the code.

```
class AccountController {
    static scaffold = Account
    def list = {
        // do something
        // invoke "super.list" i.e. the dynamically generated scaffold
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using an interceptor or a filter instead (why? much cleaner)

Controller Interceptors
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.5

Filters http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6

Answer (score -1):

Once you've done whatever you need to in your new controller, simply redirect to the original. Something along the lines of:

```
class NewController
 def doSomethingOriginal = {
    redirect(controller: "scaffoldedcontroller", action: "list", params: params)
 }
}
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: I don't want to change the action name if I can help it

Comment: You could create an inner class on your controller, overriding it that way. But, yes, filters are cleaner and probably more what you're after